# Remove specific simple markers (multiple markers for some US states that are not fully connected)

Tags: qgis

This is a follow-up of [How to create a gradient color expression in data defined properties](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104706/how-to-create-a-gradient-color-expression-in-data-defined-properties/106836#106836)

How can I remove specific centroid simple markers? For example, Florida, Kentucky, and Rhode Island all have two markers. I would like to remove one from each state.

Any ideas?

[image: Simple Markers with data defined properties (size and color) - (but too many markers)]

Comment: Couldn't you just delete the points from the layer?

Comment: I can't - Editing and selecting one rogue state point selects the other one, such that I would delete both the points (and in some cases the state as well).

Comment: Ahh multi point.  You can use the tools in QGIS to split them into single point objects.

Comment: OK - I installed multi part, but when I choose the layer that I have defined the centroid points in, and save a new output .shp file, I have the same initial issue. Is there a way to select only the points, save those all as separate polygons, and then delete the ones I need to?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is no way to tell the centroid renderer to only mark the biggest polygon of a multipolygon feature. Seems like you have to use the diagrams after all in this case.