# Color gradient in Point layer, based on attribute

Tags: pyqgis, point, symbology

I have a collection of points[nr, x, y, z] with elevation z added to the map like this:

```
...
for i in range(len(points)):
    seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(QgsPointXY(points[i][1], points[i][2])))
    scale = round((points[i][3] - minim) / diff * 90 + 10)
    seg.setAttributes([points[i][0], points[i][3], scale])
#   setOpacity(scale) or setColor(0-255/scale, 0, 0, alpha/scale)
    pr.addFeature(seg)
```

I'd like to give an idea of their topography with a color gradient, but setColor and setOpacity only apply the layer class, not the geometries? The goal is to render something like this:

[image]

I had to use 2 layers for this image and play with opacity in Layer Properties > symbology > opacity (can't find any solution in pyQGIS). Apparently you can achieve that with a single layer by changing the alpha value of the color settings, [Creating gradient point on top of shapefile using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/104680/creating-gradient-point-on-top-of-shapefile-using-qgis/104687#104687) but again I have no idea how to implement that with pyQGIS?

Comment: Setting the gradient manually as explained in the OP (linked to the scale attribute) and saving the style to a .qml stylesheet, then adding ``feat.loadNamedStyle(path_to_stylesheet)`` ``feat.triggerRepaint()`` to the script seems to be the best solution so far.